# Is pg_exec sustainable?

Tags: php

Is `pg_exec()` usable or deprecated? I've inherited a script that's using it and it seems to work, but the php.net reference is [a 404](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=pg_exec&scope=quickref). I'm not talking about the PDO `pg_execute` either.

[Random reference I've found on the function](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/manuals/php/function.pg-exec.html)

Comment: The `pg_execute` function is PostgreSQL, just like `pg_exec`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, okay. No offense intended, but I sort of had already gathered that.

Comment: Then why did you say it was the "PDO `pg_execute`"?

Comment: in addition to the answer by @VictorHenriquez, if you have the option to rewrite the script to use prepare+execute instead, probably worth doing so.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I said that it *wasn't* `pg_execute` in case someone thought I had made a typo or thought I might be misunderstanding the code I've inherited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it's called **pg-query**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php

From the manual:

> This function used to be called pg_exec(). pg_exec() is still
>   available for compatibility reasons, but users are encouraged to use
>   the newer name.

Comment: Beat me to it, was about to post it. ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir Believe me, It's the first time I'm on time :)

Comment: Yeah, you bet. When I tried last night, it was too close from when I posted and the site wouldn't let me. Answered too quickly I'm afraid..